# What's the history of Ubuntu?

Tags: canonical, history-of-ubuntu

What is the history of Ubuntu? How did Ubuntu originate? Who were the people involved?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [About Ubuntu on ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu):

> **Where did it all begin?**
>
> Linux was already established as an
>   enterprise server platform in 2004.
>   But free software was still not a part
>   of everyday life for most computer
>   users. That's why Mark Shuttleworth
>   gathered a small team of developers
>   from one of the most established Linux
>   projects – Debian - and set out to
>   create an easy-to-use Linux desktop:
>   Ubuntu.
>
> The vision for Ubuntu is part
>   social and part economic: free
>   software, available free of charge to
>   everybody on the same terms, and
>   funded through a portfolio of services
>   provided by Canonical.

To find out who was involved it is best to checkout the relevant Ubuntu mailing lists. An example would be [ubuntu-devel](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2004-September/author.html#0) from 2004 ordered by users.